# Command Button Wizard  doesn't start

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I want to create a navigation button on a web form. (I use MS Access 2010 - Web database). I dragged the button on the form (the Control Wizard option is selected) but the Command Button Wizard does not show up

I double clicked on the button, but it just let me to edit button name. I also tried to click anywhere on the form - still nothing

How do I show Command Button Wizard Menu for my "Command120" button??

[image]

Comment: Did anyone every answer your question about this issue. I have the same problem but can't seem to figure it out. thanks loretta

Comment: Unfortunately no. I left this issue unsolved as it was not the main requirement. Please answer my question if you'll solve it. though. Good luck

Comment: This bug isn't fixed even in Access 2016.

Answer (score 7):

You have to enable the control wizards first.  Go to the drop-down arrow at the end of the control group on the design ribbon and select `use control wizards`. Then insert the button again.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. I created the button the form in design mode and this seemed to get it working in layout mode again.

Comment: In my case switching to Design mode enables the wizard, but finishing the wizard crashes Access. It also ruined all VBA in my database.

Answer (score 4):

After all of the answers above, I still could not get it to work.  What appears to be the problem in my case is that the wizard will not work inside of sub-forms.  The solution is to:

- Open the sub-form directly instead of designing it inside the parent form.

or

- Create the button on the parent form, then cut or paste it to the
  sub-form.

Answer (score 2):

So this is a really old question and but I have found out the answer to the problem and will share in hopes that it may help someone in the future.

If the form is a "Web Form" the control wizards do not work. It must be a standard form. As far as I can tell there is no indication of this anywhere.  To see the difference see the image below.

[image: Two types of Forms]

The form on top is a regular form and the one whereas the one on the bottom with the little globe is a web form.  In order to create this kind of form Go to the create Tab and **DO NOT** select the options in the menu.  You must select blank form from the **Client Forms** drop down as shown below.

[image]

There you will find the option to create forms that don´t have the little globe and those are the forms that work with the control wizards.  Hope this helps someone else!  This was a real pain to discover.

Comment: Unfortunately the bug also affects regular forms. In fact, I supposed that it might be not a singular bug but a collection of them.

Answer (score 1):

Enable the "Use Control Wizards" At Design tool tab.

Then add the button to Design are.

That's all

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your wizard button in the drop down arrow is on if it is turn it off and then turn it back on then recreate your button. That worked for me in a layout view. Good Luck!!

Answer (score 0):

If Sandy's answer didn't work for you, try to switch first to **Layout View** then proceed.

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I actually landed here looking for a solution. While I didn’t find it here I did figure out what I was doing wrong.

The action wizard only works with boundControls. So the area you are trying to use is not connected to a relevant table or field.

1st off make sure that you have the wizard activated/Turned on then proceed.

Option 1 [From LayoutView]

I was able to get the wizard to work by 1st deleting the button.
Then delete the cell you are dropping the button onto.
Then I stretched the cell with a field name to the right where I wanted my button.
Then I split the fields Horizontally.
Last I dropped the button on the cell I just created adjacent to the field & voilà the wizard came-up.

Option2 [From DesignView]

Again remove what isn’t working 1st. Then drop the button where you want. The wizard should pop right up. The button won’t be where you wanted it to be, but you can always move it once you get it setup.

I read that you tried it in DesignView & it worked, but crashed Access & you lost your Macros, so just a reminder to everyone try this with a copy or test db.

HTH

Links I found helpful. 
+-------------------------------------------------------------------- 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13010098/6158704 
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introduction-to-controls-4a8cf5f2-d739-4ae9-b1e0-510c3f4d6975 
+--------------------------------------------------------------------